# Wildfly 10 JAX-WS attachements : MTOM threshold not working as expected (?)

Tags: soap, cxf, jax-ws, wildfly-10, mtom

I have JAX-WS endpoint defined with `@MTOM` annotation and set threshold as below. So I expect any attachments less 5MB shall be sent inline as `base64binary`. But the soap response is always returned as `MTOM` for even small files.

Is this expected behavior? How can I enforce this flexibility otherwise ?

```
@HandlerChain(file="/handler-chain.xml")
@MTOM(threshold=5242880) // 5MB limit for inline soap attachements else MTOM
public class WSImpl {
```

I'm interested in this [behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/mtom.htm#WSADV139). This is not the spec, but at least `Metro` implementation behaves like that (at least old version) in jboss 5. The `Apache CXF` does always sends as `MTOM` if enabled and does not care about threshold.

Comment: MTOM is only applied to base64 encoded elements  
 defined as `xs:base64Binary` in the SOAP message. Is this your use case or are you expecting SOAP attachments to be coded as base64binary? Because this second behaviour is not the target of the specification

Comment: The element is defined as `xs:base64Binary` and `MTOM` is enabled in server side. I'm interested the exact behavior mentioned in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/mtom.htm#WSADV139). It says depending on the threshold, the `xs:base64Binary` is sent as attachment or inline soap.

Comment: Then the specification is clear. It should work as an you said. Maybe it's a wildfly bug

Comment: yes, actually I think its `Apache CXF bug` which is embedded in the `wildfly`. But it is difficult to prove it in Wildfly because to replace `Metro` instead of 
 default `CXF` is nightmare.

Comment: do you know the underlying version of CXF that your server is including right now? MAy be this bug is related https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4720

Comment: Thanks. it is `Apache CXF 3.1.4` in Wildfly 10. But I have checked the behavior in `Jboss 7.2` and it is same. So apparently the CXF did not take care if the threshold is less than the provided value if found as `xop`.

Comment: I have reviewed the github repository of CXF and the threshold parameter is managed. I have reviewed the list of bugs and there is nothing, so maybe it is an undetected bug. I suggest contacting the CXF team

Comment: Thanks for your time!